# Can i config wildfly to redirect from one domain-name to another?

Tags: java, wildfly-8

I have two domain-names,

- example.com
- example1.com

both points to same ip-adress of wildfly-8 server.

Can i config wildfly so when user come to example1.com wildfly redirect him to example.com?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution in the meantime? Best regards and thanks, Toastor

Comment: @Toastor sadly, but no. the only solution i found - place nginx in front and allow him to proxy requests from each domain to single server-side on wild-fly

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I found my own solution and posted it as an answer, although it doesn't really answer the question. I'm under the impression that you can't solve it by configuration so the "correct" answer would probably be: "No!" :)

Answer (score 0):

While not precisely an answer to the original question (since it doesn't work by just making changes to the wildfly config), here's how I solved it:

I have been using [ocpsoft rewrite](http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/). With rewrite, you can make URLs look more pretty and in fact, I had been using it for this purpose for quite some time already. But it was only recently that I found out that it doesn't only work with the path but with the domain part as well.

All you need to do is adding the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
   <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
   <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Implement a configuration provider:

```
@RewriteConfiguration
public class RewriteConfigurationProvider extends HttpConfigurationProvider {

   @Override
   public int priority() {
      return 10;
   }

   @Override
   public Configuration getConfiguration(final ServletContext context) {

      return ConfigurationBuilder.begin()

            .addRule()
            .when(Direction.isInbound().and(Domain.matches("www.somedomain.de")).and(Path.matches("{path}")))
            .perform(Redirect.permanent("http://www.someotherdomain.de{path}"))
            .where("path").matches(".*")

            .addRule(Join.path("/prettypath").to("/pretty.xhtml").withInboundCorrection())
            .addRule(Join.path("/prettypathwithparam/{id}").to("pretty.xhtml").withInboundCorrection());

   }

}
```

And that's it!

I even like this better than I would reconfiguring wildfly, because it is more powerful, if you need it. For example, you could let your application logic decide wether to redirect a request or not, count the number of incoming visitors on each domain, make dynamic use of subdomains, and more.

Disclosure...: I'm not affiliated to ocpsoft in any way except that I'm a happy user of their libraries :)